# Boost.Log flush after each logging statement

Tags: c++, logging, boost, boost-log

I'm a bit new to Boost.Log library, first impressions are really good, but one thing is already took a lot of hours and I can't solve it. I want to make Boost.Log to write each message to a log file immediately. I'm aware of other questions ([I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113229/boost-log-logging-an-applications-critical-errors), [II](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17888572/how-can-i-manually-flush-a-boost-log), [III](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391570/boostlog-add-file-log-not-writing-if-app-exits-with-ctrl-close-event)), however they didn't help. Consider this [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/log/example/doc/tutorial_file_manual.cpp) from boost docs, the next code is the same except that I've set `auto_flush` to `true`:

```
namespace logging = boost::log;
namespace src = boost::log::sources;
namespace sinks = boost::log::sinks;

void init()
{
    // Construct the sink
    typedef sinks::synchronous_sink< sinks::text_ostream_backend > text_sink;
    boost::shared_ptr< text_sink > sink = boost::make_shared< text_sink >();

    // Add a stream to write log to
    sink->locked_backend()->add_stream(
        boost::make_shared< std::ofstream >("sample.log")); //1

    sink->locked_backend()->auto_flush(true);

    // Register the sink in the logging core
    logging::core::get()->add_sink(sink);
}

int main(int, char*[])
{
    init();

    src::logger lg;
    BOOST_LOG(lg) << "Hello world!";

    return 0;
}
```

While debugging, an empty `sample.log` is created after execution of first command (//1), however after executing BOOST_LOG, log file remains empty, only after `return` statement, `Hello world!` is written to log file.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did some research. Consider next changed `main` function:

```
int main(int, char*[])
{
    init();

    src::logger lg;
    BOOST_LOG(lg) << "Hello world #1!";
    BOOST_LOG(lg) << "Hello world #2!";
    std::cin.get();
    BOOST_LOG(lg) << "Hello world #3!";
    BOOST_LOG(lg) << "Hello world #4!";

    return 0;
}
```

So `std::cin.get()` acts as pause, launch application in normal mode (without debugging, Ctrl + F5 from VS2008, or simply executing `*.exe`from `Debug` folder) and when you reach input part (`std::cin.get()`) just go to Task Manager and kill the process. Depending on value of `auto_flush` results are next:

- `auto_flush(false)` -- log file is empty!
- `auto_flush(true)` -- log file will contain first two records, made before `std::cin.get()`

Changing `std::cin.get()` to `throw 1` gives always first two records being written to log file, regarding of if `auto_flush` set to `true` or `false` both in `Release` and `Debug` builds.

So, the conclusion is that `auto_flush` works fine, it's just has a bit strange behaviour when debugging directly from Visual Studio.